# Share methods across processes in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I want to be able to share methods across different `node.js` processes created using the cluster module.

If I run the code below I can share the method `server.handleRequest` across the child processes, however If I uncomment `//server.test();` in the second file and try to use the method `test` in the original process, node crashes.

```
"use strict";

var os = require('os');
var http = require('http');
var cluster = require('cluster');

function testMethod() {
  console.log('Test');
}

function handleRequest(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("This answer comes from the process " + process.pid);
}

var createServer = function createServer(opts) {

  var server = {};

  server.test = testMethod;

  server.handleRequest = handleRequest;

  if (cluster.isMaster) {

    var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

    for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    return server;

  } else {

    // Create HTTP server.
    http.Server(function(req, res) {
      server.handleRequest(req, res);
    }).listen(8080);
  }
}

module.exports = {

  createServer: createServer,

};
```

The second file that includes the above file.

```
"use strict";

var router = require('./test.js');

var server = router.createServer();

//server.test();
```

But If I don't use the cluster module I can use the `test` method outside the factory function with out crashing. So how do I share methods created in factory functions across all node processes, while using the cluster module? And why do the child processes execute `test` when only the original process calls `server.test()`?

```
var http = require('http');

function testMethod() {
  console.log('Test');
}

function handleRequest(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("This answer comes from the process " + process.pid);
}

var createServer = function createServer(opts) {

  var server = {};

  server.test = testMethod;
  server.handleRequest = handleRequest;

  http.Server(function(req, res) {
    server.handleRequest(req, res);
  }).listen(8080);

  return server;
}

module.exports = {

  createServer: createServer,

};
```

Comment: put said method in a common module that can be required by them all.

Comment: on child processes you are not returning anything. so `server` is undefined. try adding `test` method as a prototype of `createServer `

Comment: Why are the child processes even executing `test` if the main process is the only one calling it?

Comment: your if conditional. If it's master, you returned `server`, else, you didn't. So for all that wasn't master, you wouldn't have a `server` object with a `test` property and they'd fail if they try to call `server.test()`

Comment: Ok, if I add `return server` to the child it dose not crash, but It executes `test` in each child process and I only call it once in the main process, so why does it execute multiple times?